# MySQL memory table import "the table is full"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a dumped memory table (created with `mysqldump`) on an new machine (for replication).

It fails with the error message:

> the table is full

As far as I can tell, all relevant settings (including `max_heap_table_size`) are equal on both the source and destination server.

Are there any more known issues, or settings I need, that can cause the above error?

Comment: Is the engine for the table you're importing to still MEMORY?

Comment: @Warner, Yes (the table definition is also in the dump file).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions to be asked:

1. Are the tables dumped and imported defined identically?
2. Do you have an indexes on the table you are importing?

I would think that the simplest solution might be increasing the `max_heap_table_size` value in the configuration and once you finish the import compare the size of the table data.